# subscribeToChannels not working

Tags: ios, iphone, object, pubnub

I working on cab applicantion, in wich there is app for driver.
I have to configure PubNub and subscribe to driver channel for particular driver.

So what i did is :

First configure client :

```
PNConfiguration *configuration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:kPublishKey subscribeKey:kSubscribeKey];
self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:configuration];
[self.client addListener:self];
```

Than after i subscribe to channel in that channel contain all driver so i send CAB_ID for that driver who logged in Like :

```
  NSDictionary *clientState = @{@"id": [[dicData valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"id"],
                                 @"rate": @"1.77",
                                 @"price": @"4",
                                 @"status" : @"Online",
                                 @"hold": @"0",
                                 @"ac_type": @"0",
                                 @"gender": [[dicData valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"gender"],
                                 @"bearing": @"213.68757972878151",
                                 @"lng": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitude],
                                 @"lat": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude],
                                 @"driver_type": [[dicData valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"profile_type"],
                                 @"cab_type": @"hatchback",
                                 @"full_name": [[dicData valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"first_name"]
                                 };

    [self.client subscribeToChannels:@[kDriverMyChannel,@"CAB_250"] withPresence:YES clientState:clientState];
```

but it not effecting my panel, it not logging to driver channel.
Please help.

Comment: Where's your [subscribe listener code](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe-sdk-v4#publishing_and_subscribing_to_a_channel)?